# Lost user click while updating a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, click

I've got a somewhat "big" div (containing almost my whole page) and every second I do a
mydiv.empty() and then I rebuild it entirely.

I know it's not efficient at all but for now this will have to do for my code :/ The issue is that some inner div of "mydiv" have click event attached to them. And sometime, when the use click, the input is lost and never taken ito consideration by the inner div.

I tried to catch all click on my page with a document.click(). It did catch some lost click but many of them are still lost.

It seems those clicks occurs somewhere between the mydiv.empty() and the big mydiv.append() that re-creates all its content. I can't find a solution to grab these lost clicks. Any idea?

PS : I know I could probably get away by restructuring my whole page and updating more specific part of my div instead of recreating it but for now i'd like to find a faster/cheaper solution before redoing all this :)

Cheers !

EDit : as requested :

```
when (timer > 1 sec) 
{ 
mydivContent = "lots of things here, including a small inner div"
mydiv.empty()
mydiv.append(mydivContent)
innerdiv.click(function..)
}
```

The lower the timer is, the more clicks are not registered by the innerdiv.click() event

Comment: Of course you lose all events if you delete the objects which own these events! If you then create new objects, maybe exact copies of the last ones, they **are not** the same objects, so they don't have the events. You need to set the events also to the new objects - or, as you mentioned, get away from restructuring your page and update only specific parts.

Comment: My post may not have been clear, sorry. I know I need to recreate all my cliks event and I Do. it's just that the faster ill refresh my div, the more clicks will still be lost. They are lost between a call to empty() and append() I think. [to recreate my div]

Comment: What do you mean with `clicks are lost`? Do you mean that if the user clicks in the time between `empty()` and `append()` these clicks are lost...?

Comment: I mean that they are not registered by anything on my pages, not even the document since i can get the click even with a document.click() function. It must be linked to the way i refresh my div because if I lower the refresh rate of the page, I can ealisy click on my innerdiv and nothing is getting lost. But the faster i refresh my page and thus the more .empty() and .append() I use, the more click will never get to my code.

Comment: without example of code this is all a guess as to what might be happening

Comment: edit: psuedo code added

Comment: Your code isn't very meaningful, I'm sorry. Please add the relevant parts of **your code** and not anything nebulous.